# Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object on server only

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

This is quite bizarre. I have the code running on localhost fine whereas throwing error on my digital ocean server. Here is my code;

Provide.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

In my controller. ProvideController.php

```
 $helper = ProvideHelp::where('id', 1)->first();
```

In my view i have

```
<tr>
   <th scope="row">Amount</th>
   <td>₦{{ $helper->amount }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">Name</th>
  <td>{{ $helper->user->full_name }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row"> Phone Number</th>
    <td>{{ $helper->user }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Locally it works fine but on my server i get the following error

```
Trying to get property 'full_name' of non-object
```

I would appreciate it if i can be pointed out as to why this is so

Comment: what is inside `$helper` ? from where you r getting?

Comment: sorry from my providehelp model. WIll update it now

Comment: Check the user exists? `ProvideHelp` in the db check `user_id` and check that user exists?

Comment: @DilipHirapara the user exists. just fine.

Comment: You can use ternary operator to ignore this error, `{{ $helper->user->full_name ?? '-' }}`, but this happened when you call the relationship and that collection doesn't exist.

Comment: it's probably because user with id 1 does not exist on your remote database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$helper = ProvideHelp::with('user')->where('id', 1)->first();
```